# using VideoView twice in one layout

Tags: java, android

On create, im trying to play two videos at one time. I am currently using two videoviews. Firstly, should i create buttons to start the video views or should I use MediaController? Also, I have haerd that two VideoViews will not work. Is this true and if so, is there a way around it.

Thanks,

XcutionX

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot play two VideoViews at one time. If you want to show more, I recommend looking at [TextureViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) (If you are targeting Ice Cream Sandwich or above, I'd recommend using TextureViews regardless).

It makes no real difference if you want to handle the play state with buttons or with the MediaController. Do whatever you think looks right.